# Сортировка таблицы выполняется неверно

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, при сортировке таблицы на возрастание/убывание, выходит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

соответственно, нужно чтобы сортировка была 1,2,3,4,5,6,7... и т.д. по порядку

```js
<script>
document.title = "[LL_REPTAG_MYID NODEINFO:NAME /]";

function sortId(){
 var pretype = $("#pretype_sort").text();
 if(pretype == "" || pretype == "desc"){
  $("#pretype_sort").text("asc");
 }else{
  $("#pretype_sort").text("desc")
 }
 
 
   var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
  table = document.getElementById("sorting_table");
   switching = true;
   /* Make a loop that will continue until
   no switching has been done: */
   while (switching) {
  // Start by saying: no switching is done:
  switching = false;
  rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
  /* Loop through all table rows (except the
  first, which contains table headers): */
  for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 2); i++) {
    // Start by saying there should be no switching:
    shouldSwitch = false;
    /* Get the two elements you want to compare,
    one from current row and one from the next: */
    x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
    y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
    // Check if the two rows should switch place:
    if(pretype == "" || pretype == "desc"){
     if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
    // I so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
    shouldSwitch= true;
    break;
     }
    }else{
    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
    // I so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
    shouldSwitch= true;
    break;
     }
    }
    
  }
  if (shouldSwitch) {
    /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
    and mark that a switch has been done: */
    rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
    switching = true;
  }
   }
}
 
</script>
```

Comment: Результат явно показывает, что Вы сортируете данные как строки, а не как числа. Да и `toLowerCase` в операторах сравнения говорит о том же. Ну или добавьте им ведущих нулей...

Comment: Вы не можете подсказать, как это реализовать ?

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема, что вы работаете с таким типом данных, как текст, а вам нужны цифры иначе

```js
var a = $("#pretype_sort").text(); 
var b = Number(a);
```

и так везде после сортировка заработает правильно

Answer (score 0):

Приведите явно в числовому типу используя parseInt()
Либо, если есть возможность использовать современные браузеры, можно использовать [Collator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator)

Comment: Я не вникал в ваш код, но предполагаю, что в первой ячейке каждой строки у вас целое число, которое вы хотите сравнить.

`x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
    y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];

    if(pretype == "" || pretype == "desc"){
     if (parseInt(x.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) > parseInt(y.innerHTML.toLowerCase())) {

    shouldSwitch= true;
    break;
     }
    }else{
    if (parseInt(x.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) < parseInt(y.innerHTML.toLowerCase())) {
    shouldSwitch= true;
    break;
     }
    }`